# Get HTML element attribute from javascript

Tags: javascript

I stuck again in beginner-spheres of JS. :/

I want to get the number from `data-channel-id`, which is found by the call in variable `spans`:

```
<main class="soft--top" data-channel-id="348" data-preview-mode="">
```

This is my JS:

```
window.onload = function (){
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0];
var res = /[0-9]+/;
var match = res.exec(spans);
console.log(match); 
 }
```

I don't know how to proceed. 
The Regex is correct, the document. variable "spans" shows the correct result, but matching won't show any output in the console.

What am I missing?

Comment: [`spans.getAttribute('data-channel-id')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Comment: You don't need to use regex. Use `getAttribute` as @Zenoo commented already.

Comment: See w3schools page for the already mentioned `getAttribute(...)` method: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp

Comment: Please don't link to w3schools, MDN has a much better and more reliable doc.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. This made it for me:

Comment: `window.onload = function (){
      var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('main')   [0].getAttribute("data-channel-id");
  console.log(spans); 
 }`

Answer (score 0):

`spans` in your code currently contains the whole element.

To use only the `data-channel-id` value, see the code below:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].getAttribute('data-channel-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

`spans` is not string but HTMLElement, to get value of `data-channel-id` you can use `getAttribute` as mentioned in comment above or if you really want to use regex convert it to string with `.outerHTML`

```
window.onload = function() {
  var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0];
  var res = /[0-9]+/;
  var match = res.exec(spans.outerHTML);
  console.log(match);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the number from "data-channel-id"

No need to use regex. Just:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0];
var match = spans.getAttribute('data-channel-id');
console.log(match);
```

Working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rrtsey9z/).